# Routing power return path between battery holders on opposite edges of the PCB

Tags: batteries, pcb, layout, routing, return-current

What is the best way to route the current path between two battery holders on opposite edges of the board where the shortest, most direct path would cross clock generator or would be near a sensitive amplifier?

The following screenshot shows first steps of a board layout. This is in the phase of fitting the board into a case, thus components of sub modules are already clustered and I'm still shifting things around.

[image: Board scribble showing battery holders on opposite edges and HF and analog circuitry in-between/near direct battery-to-battery path]

(The traces are only scribbled, I know they're not fully connected.)

The above example shows the battery-battery path routed along the board edges, as far away from other components as possible.

J1 through J3 are alternate battery connector jacks and pads. SW1 is a rotary switch. Expected battery current is << 100mA.

As far as I know routes crossing each other in 90° angles (i.e. connecting top minus to bottom plus with the most direct path) should be acceptable as coupling is negligible. However it would split my ground plane.

Thus I refrained from using the shortest path.

The limiting factor so far is the case dimensions: I don't want it to be wider, longer or thicker, use the available case space most efficiently while keeping good weight balance.

Ruled out so far:

- Placing the battery holder on the bottom (height exceeded)
- Using a Li-Po battery (I prefer AAAs)
- Using a more compact switch (acceptable, though a little bit more expensive)

Questions:

- **What drawback does the above layout have?**
- **Would you suggest finding a battery holder placement with the holders next to each other, compromising layout?**

Comment: Having the batteries next to each other would certainly be preferred from a layout standpoint. But my question is, why do you think the batteries are going to generate interference? Batteries are virtually the cleanest DC source you can use practically. Your layout concerns are more related to SMPS. The layout seems reasonable as it is (green battery traces).

Comment: My concern is two fold: 1) the DC/DC will cause pulsed current draw from the battery, which may couple into the amplifier section 2) although the long battery-battery path reduced coupling it might be problematic due to higher HF impedance (negligible?).

Comment: If you decouple the DCDC convertor properly, you won't have AC in the battery loop. I would be more concerned with the 100kHz clock contaminating the analog. Ironically, making a larger battery loop is counter-productive to your argument. Small, tight loops are preferred from an EMC standpoint (radiated and immunity).

Comment: Interestingly I considered the loop**area** (the whole bounding box) to be smaller with the battery path kept as close to the edges as possible.

Comment: with the batteries fixed where you have them, the shortest loop would have the trace run directly under the battery; going farther to the edge increases loop area. Obviously this is only a small increase, and if that's a problem, you have much bigger PCB problems. The shortest loop-area could be made with a double battery pack where the batteries are side-by-side.

Comment: One other thing you can consider is having the battery return path on the ground plane. That way you can run the other battery connection directly over the return path which is an even tighter loop than 2 power traces side-by-side. Remember, at high-frequency, current travels on planes through the path of least impedance, not least resistance. And the path of least impedance is the path right under the HF trace.